# App crashes on iPad only on iOS 9.3.2

Tags: ios, crash, crash-log

After submitting my app for review yesterday, I just received a response back from the App Store Review team saying that my app crashes on an iPad running iOS 9.3.2. They sent me this crash log if anyone can help decipher it?

```
Incident Identifier: C87E86CE-8967-4E35-ADD4-76CEBBAFB91F
CrashReporter Key:   fa4625ce7ada9ef45852db2e109c9fae360263fc
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Lunge for the Lorit [525]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1BF953D5-3ED1-4685-A0BC-B5A9EDB4EBFD/Lunge for the Lorit.app/Lunge for the Lorit
Identifier:          com.Neil-Shweky.Lunge-for-the-Lorit
Version:             3 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-05-26 13:59:25.25 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-05-26 13:58:23.23 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1836eee38 0x182d53f80 0x1835cf084 0x1001005f4 0x10012a060 0x10012a310 0x10013dbac 0x1831394bc 0x18313947c 0x18313eb84 0x1836a4dd8 0x1836a2c40 0x1835ccd10 0x184eb4088 0x188899f70 0x100103b68 0x18316a8b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018328811c 0x18326c000 + 114972
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183354ef8 0x183350000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001831f9dac 0x183198000 + 400812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182d2d3f4 0x182d2c000 + 5108
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182d49e98 0x182d2c000 + 122520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182d54248 0x182d4c000 + 33352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182d46f44 0x182d2c000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182d4685c 0x182d2c000 + 108636
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182d54094 0x182d4c000 + 32916
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001835cf084 0x1835c4000 + 45188
10  Lunge for the Lorit             0x00000001001005f4 0x1000f8000 + 34292
11  Lunge for the Lorit             0x000000010012a060 0x1000f8000 + 204896
12  Lunge for the Lorit             0x000000010012a310 0x1000f8000 + 205584
13  Lunge for the Lorit             0x000000010013dbac 0x1000f8000 + 285612
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001831394bc 0x183138000 + 5308
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018313947c 0x183138000 + 5244
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018313eb84 0x183138000 + 27524
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836a4dd8 0x1835c4000 + 921048
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836a2c40 0x1835c4000 + 912448
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001835ccd10 0x1835c4000 + 36112
20  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184eb4088 0x184ea8000 + 49288
21  UIKit                           0x0000000188899f70 0x18881c000 + 515952
22  Lunge for the Lorit             0x0000000100103b68 0x1000f8000 + 47976
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018316a8b8 0x183168000 + 10424

Activity ID:             0x0000000000008aa5
Activity Name:           send control actions
Activity Image Path:     /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
Activity Image UUID:     74822453-A347-3710-A19D-8E14887476ED
Activity Offset:         0x000345d8
Activity Running Time:   0.330188 sec



Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001832894d8 0x18326c000 + 120024
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018314c7d8 0x183138000 + 83928
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018313b648 0x183138000 + 13896

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018326cfd8 0x18326c000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018326ce54 0x18326c000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836a4ce8 0x1835c4000 + 920808
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836a29ec 0x1835c4000 + 911852
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001835ccd10 0x1835c4000 + 36112
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183d4daf4 0x183ca0000 + 711412
6   Foundation                      0x00000001840c3e1c 0x183fd0000 + 998940
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183353b28 0x183350000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183353a8c 0x183350000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351028 0x183350000 + 4136

Thread 3 name:  com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018326cfd8 0x18326c000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018326ce54 0x18326c000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836a4ce8 0x1835c4000 + 920808
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836a29ec 0x1835c4000 + 911852
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001835ccd10 0x1835c4000 + 36112
5   Foundation                      0x0000000183fdcd8c 0x183fd0000 + 52620
6   Lunge for the Lorit             0x00000001001765bc 0x1000f8000 + 517564
7   Foundation                      0x00000001840c3e1c 0x183fd0000 + 998940
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183353b28 0x183350000 + 15144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183353a8c 0x183350000 + 14988
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351028 0x183350000 + 4136

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183288b48 0x18326c000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351530 0x183350000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351020 0x183350000 + 4128

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183288344 0x18326c000 + 115524
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836ab250 0x1835c4000 + 946768
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183353b28 0x183350000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183353a8c 0x183350000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351028 0x183350000 + 4136

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183288b48 0x18326c000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351530 0x183350000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351020 0x183350000 + 4128

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183288b48 0x18326c000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351530 0x183350000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351020 0x183350000 + 4128

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183288b48 0x18326c000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351530 0x183350000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183351020 0x183350000 + 4128

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000157f34367
    x4: 0x0000000182d4ae02   x5: 0x000000016fd05570   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x00000000ffffffff  x15: 0x00000000fffffffb
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a1770000  x21: 0x000000016fd05570  x22: 0x000000015900b540  x23: 0x0000000000000009
   x24: 0x00000001a0857000  x25: 0x000000016fd06be0  x26: 0x00000001a1775080  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd054d0   lr: 0x0000000183354ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fd054b0   pc: 0x000000018328811c cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1000f8000 - 0x1001c3fff Lunge for the Lorit arm64  <b936aefbe1c83c35a9fa74ea51b38713> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1BF953D5-3ED1-4685-A0BC-B5A9EDB4EBFD/Lunge for the Lorit.app/Lunge for the Lorit
0x120090000 - 0x1200bffff dyld arm64  <b9ab8d2475913f8c9974747a7feab615> /usr/lib/dyld
0x182cd4000 - 0x182cd5fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <52b7493178a73db5a7c54a56277f6541> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x182cd8000 - 0x182d2afff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <9ec0d9dcf728349582c26a7da72f0364> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x182d2c000 - 0x182d4bfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <aaa40b7f52513cf79c6f814b133556a7> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x182d4c000 - 0x1830b8fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <939f392022903f2da2858e676e4191ef> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1830bc000 - 0x1830c0fff libcache.dylib arm64  <fa36de9ad21a393eb3a7127c04d04ca5> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1830c4000 - 0x1830cffff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <12c1227794b43b27912ee75bd2137ff8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1830d0000 - 0x1830d3fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <73834c4aa3f43c02a845058ff8d68c64> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1830d4000 - 0x1830dbfff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <95710fca746b3ba38af88436a380b4fb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1830dc000 - 0x183137fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <76284b3e49dc3625b32b880276def64d> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x183138000 - 0x183166fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <4b14d83138ad33379b3bd854ef5a4a4a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x183168000 - 0x18316afff libdyld.dylib arm64  <f953f45560ee3d64aea214b5fcd983d4> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x18316c000 - 0x18316cfff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <d5d3b9a499d534d6ad2bb6593ec11bb5> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x183170000 - 0x183174fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <907ec5ae27a03f568b095b7c03704e8f> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x183178000 - 0x183179fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <1bceda69f6553e6686db67d99681f6d9> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18317c000 - 0x183192fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <40c47f76cc9437538506e1e009e65b5b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x183194000 - 0x183195fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <8bbf799e57f93ed1be24cf2ce6c221a3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x183198000 - 0x183217fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <e9ce2b001e2a315ea945b3625892f3d1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x183218000 - 0x18321bfff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <8e558d3dc4ab3172829609a21264333b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x18321c000 - 0x18321ffff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <881e67201afb30e4923fe629f2038c39> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x183220000 - 0x183221fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <fb091931e5a73a91b83eaa86ac092846> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x183224000 - 0x18323afff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <e72136cd079a38f397bbda2e943853a9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x18323c000 - 0x183244fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <106cc81ae1ef3558bc9e92640e0f53ed> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x183248000 - 0x18326afff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <0cc7938fabaf3ce0add0b1bd8b0b7940> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x18326c000 - 0x18328dfff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <c2c8abd01c0a301e918dd274425de8d2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x183290000 - 0x1832acfff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <82799adce569363d85ad8e859eb07117> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1832b0000 - 0x1832c9fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <f5f102a4b15539d5957d18fcc0a1da6a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1832cc000 - 0x18332ffff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <a1d92752abf138349ebbfe35e00eb642> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x183330000 - 0x183339fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <2d91232a517d3ab9b2c7080fa281d59e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x18333c000 - 0x183346fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <694e057c9ba33bb783d565d6b681ef4d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x183348000 - 0x18334dfff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <60beb51b46eb31d2a359385285705935> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x183350000 - 0x183358fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <de359eedd23d3f37b7f493e5c141ab87> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x18335c000 - 0x18335efff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <98a5ef772798365db3cad61eda9e8087> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x183360000 - 0x183370fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <40f1aab82aee39f591243fd2fe0ebe60> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x183374000 - 0x183379fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <b0067e5ea3ca3b28abc5cb7d50390363> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x18337c000 - 0x18337cfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <3602a453d2b132e5beedf06ffd6c5543> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x183380000 - 0x1833a5fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <077984f90ff93b6abdb00e26e03d0bd9> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1833a8000 - 0x1835adfff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <2113459c857d3a79b7a2f3744a9cc7aa> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1835b0000 - 0x1835c1fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <8fcb56adfdc13e9593582266b1e4ac18> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1835c4000 - 0x183944fff CoreFoundation arm64  <47efbe0ae95f31e289bc13ae81db5ed5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x183948000 - 0x183958fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <d045301bcacc37d785d754d5c978d979> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x18395c000 - 0x18395cfff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <6638c84011613491bf818da9d271d34d> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x183960000 - 0x1839d1fff IOKit arm64  <cdb241ec26593ce58bafe5775a6b32ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1839d4000 - 0x1839f4fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <56afd8ee124b33a58b536846d3bb37ee> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1839f8000 - 0x183ae2fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <727d77fd6455370ea52e4173245fa667> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x183ae4000 - 0x183b56fff Security arm64  <1e7c7854a0183825be581e308b6d6048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x183b58000 - 0x183bb1fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <0ca82735132034eea5f9b2c64e15cdf9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x183bb4000 - 0x183c9cfff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <c703a175f1c43ed28d81b839ba961183> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x183ca0000 - 0x183f34fff CFNetwork arm64  <9d2c89aa29143c1f967d455d14e2cc48> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x183f38000 - 0x183f45fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <8ebfd413e3fd3889b546857fcf554b6f> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x183f48000 - 0x183f61fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <68bb861dc8bd3547b5ace073ed504b14> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x183f64000 - 0x183f7efff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <1a2c1f709f213faf81fd2223b719c899> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x183f80000 - 0x183faafff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <bf6ae1a9c965363ba9f10ff0ca32ee7c> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x183fac000 - 0x183fcafff libextension.dylib arm64  <8a88fb35fee03a36ae138e676b9a0e9f> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x183fcc000 - 0x183fcdfff liblangid.dylib arm64  <cdb184e30c3c303694a96b3150520673> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x183fd0000 - 0x18423efff Foundation arm64  <d0203ca50e6c319eab2c67be2233a1df> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x184240000 - 0x1842ebfff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <097b7e769a3439ad8fdb3abb0edc9daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x1842ec000 - 0x184651fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <566419f65c9338599694a04da8e20fbf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x184654000 - 0x1848b9fff vImage arm64  <789df1b35e183397803583a25feff3c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1848bc000 - 0x1848defff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <b9bacd899d76330faf8470b537cd316c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1848e0000 - 0x1848f3fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <94d099e954d638e39ef1773639ef61af> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1848f4000 - 0x184903fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <80ca4fb770613c76b2449daf05c6dc25> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x184904000 - 0x184970fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f4e8d68f55af3511a28a616737dcc354> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x184974000 - 0x184974fff vecLib arm64  <546ad53c3a4a36709fdf6e50b76b2ec9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x184978000 - 0x184978fff Accelerate arm64  <a1953e95570a3de6a923a812ffbd90ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x18497c000 - 0x184ea7fff CoreGraphics arm64  <47d407b528a33cbba05a8944ecd81a65> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x184ea8000 - 0x184ebcfff GraphicsServices arm64  <7275e531cb4934bc81dcf548ec07315d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x184ec0000 - 0x184f08fff AppSupport arm64  <f822dd316d913e46b63f4ff0a9b3ab38> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x184f0c000 - 0x184fdffff MobileCoreServices arm64  <5b596a6b0d2234a7b53cd64c3a805453> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x184fe0000 - 0x18502ffff BaseBoard arm64  <51ea416f98da37b5bf3c8dd40a19881a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x185030000 - 0x18503bfff AssertionServices arm64  <de762838b13a3e9ca15b115554b90b33> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18503c000 - 0x185060fff BackBoardServices arm64  <174df085ac00343fa8dc017d6ff4f291> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x185064000 - 0x185067fff MobileSystemServices arm64  <6d85ae92680935bbb51db96c7a021118> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x185068000 - 0x18509dfff FrontBoardServices arm64  <7aa900b6c1503aca868d369472dafd7b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1850a0000 - 0x1850aafff UserNotificationServices arm64  <8cdf10472ed037548f8c9f2d22eab649> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserNotificationServices.framework/UserNotificationServices
0x1850ac000 - 0x1850d8fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <9a77d7611b593b86b61a7ed2a5be04de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x1850dc000 - 0x1850edfff MobileKeyBag arm64  <1b24eb8193c53b39a3f92eae6c705c87> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1850f0000 - 0x1850f6fff IOSurface arm64  <f034e73c669c3d4fb297c56390224f08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x1850f8000 - 0x185104fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <602aacfa051b3bd8b96645e243c47b47> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x185108000 - 0x18511afff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <3e279e8083563cdfb9e0085f7cd3571c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18511c000 - 0x18511efff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <00180a1accdf3d9aa8f608c0d215f09c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x185120000 - 0x185161fff AppleJPEG arm64  <24fc6e2cd59a318e9f59da6383bfd90d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x185164000 - 0x185486fff ImageIO arm64  <795af361b422367d8b41019c99f32d5d> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x185488000 - 0x18548cfff TCC arm64  <2e55d766befe3cae904179e14b10356a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x185490000 - 0x185495fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <313f770947da3c39ab514bbb85112d7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x185498000 - 0x1854a5fff PowerLog arm64  <7648bc055de832fcb788bafe0fd75832> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1854a8000 - 0x18550afff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <8096d53d8a9632b49c76633234c3a99f> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x18550c000 - 0x18551efff CommonUtilities arm64  <f9508e3c884d30848237ac33a6d41aab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x185520000 - 0x185537fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <ac77f3a3cad832a7b748c30e013bbc0b> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x185538000 - 0x185782fff CoreData arm64  <2c14605cb1213ce68fb271bd442a88c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x185784000 - 0x185788fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <7ffd8b3397af377e9a66196013879b3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x18578c000 - 0x185790fff IOAccelerator arm64  <335e831484b5324d9935e64e4f7a199a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x185794000 - 0x185795fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <65fbe0a7fb243dc591a5ce214f685de9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x185798000 - 0x18579bfff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <e6fddb40c1ff3369860604ca0198543a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x18579c000 - 0x1857e2fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <46d0426799633b81bc7857f541610374> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1857e4000 - 0x1857eefff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <958a1f782d9736d6a59b8081000ea746> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x1857f0000 - 0x1857f7fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <277c1e7b811b37d9b43b886f1b1344ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x1857f8000 - 0x1857f8fff libmetal_timestamp.dylib arm64  <8096dc344d98384cb0814ad5e96ffc47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x1857fc000 - 0x185842fff Metal arm64  <fa567a39d48830b0ad7689fe5d54ff82> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x185844000 - 0x18584efff OpenGLES arm64  <76508ee5702530a1ad5c5f7e793564d3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x185850000 - 0x185872fff CoreVideo arm64  <a897c32ee73a3ea189748e1874f94818> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x185874000 - 0x185876fff OAuth arm64  <a7bcf8406f27378dbe366eccb7be15ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x185878000 - 0x1858affff Accounts arm64  <83ae9cc3aaa43344b1cf039bcf99fc1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1858b0000 - 0x1859a2fff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <1c378c57054a32a6b2eed4e3cbb3a2b7> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x1859a4000 - 0x185a5dfff CoreAudio arm64  <fa891ecfffc8337ba959f989a00a7927> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x185a60000 - 0x185a63fff UserFS arm64  <99274b169cba305385ade60b9b105cef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x185a64000 - 0x185b52fff CoreMedia arm64  <2af541a013183d4191d23e17e1eaa35c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x185b54000 - 0x185b5cfff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <0b8ff222e751316b97a684f75854b828> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x185b60000 - 0x185bd2fff CoreTelephony arm64  <4c8319d593bf3e48b83ff2052e5baf13> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x185bd4000 - 0x185cb4fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <4dbd2916349c3ebb93f77b45246f4623> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x185cb8000 - 0x185d3afff VideoToolbox arm64  <319868e498543abcb034fdcdd8b32bca> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x185d3c000 - 0x185d3cfff FontServices arm64  <e478d00caed23555a1f669d00ac5d63e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x185d40000 - 0x185e63fff CoreText arm64  <89eb3b018d263de896ecdb031294ea1e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x185e64000 - 0x185e75fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <8f52f98261263182b7dfe4c5128c89b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x185e78000 - 0x185e9ffff PersistentConnection arm64  <7933d9b31dab3c86baf9b58f142d97f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x185ea0000 - 0x185ea5fff DataMigration arm64  <26f93fc1499a3ae1b2da4cafd65c9474> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x185ea8000 - 0x1861c1fff AudioToolbox arm64  <4e885a8735ef31098c27000ffdad8a0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x1861c4000 - 0x186372fff QuartzCore arm64  <cb08f57edbcc3749bb529b611f14ede7> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x186374000 - 0x18637afff Netrb arm64  <0e9744efb928344994af8d9d34aa6463> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x18637c000 - 0x18638dfff libcmph.dylib arm64  <f9b0e4b1c2b83f848b351670183dcf24> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x186390000 - 0x1863adfff libmis.dylib arm64  <70703ed0aad23e11b2ef2eaddfcb3c2f> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x1863b0000 - 0x186430fff LanguageModeling arm64  <63d077132a3b39bc898ad6ad0d37ebb0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x186434000 - 0x18650efff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <853d10047c8637239f7fa69fab096cdf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x186510000 - 0x186527fff libmarisa.dylib arm64  <72aff9de7b7a3d0f8d24b2f2e33599b1> /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
0x186528000 - 0x1865effff ProofReader arm64  <1109bbdb73d5392693809d31fe5b2406> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x1865f0000 - 0x1865f6fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <dbc84b51887d3c239f748993bfe87be2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x1865f8000 - 0x186607fff MobileAsset arm64  <7240eaffafed3f478cc74cd1d78a043c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x186608000 - 0x186669fff ColorSync arm64  <7a7f1de762e734a1b0185bbcf4c5805d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x18666c000 - 0x1866b7fff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64  <ba4fb9bec10b345fb558c8167aa9c19f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x1866b8000 - 0x186ae4fff FaceCore arm64  <e94d54babc7b308bb8f72aad65b08421> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x186ae8000 - 0x186b63fff Quagga arm64  <a2b834549b2a34e5bf5c5ef4810273ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x186b64000 - 0x186d0efff CoreImage arm64  <186c1bbb975530bf92774b12ebffb735> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x186d10000 - 0x186d42fff TextInput arm64  <df26e8d9906536a28882920ed911bebd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x186d44000 - 0x186d51fff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <9c8c638a431038a2b35ce180666ccf2d> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x186d60000 - 0x187341fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <f476e19d9f4738d5ac4352faa0d7f24c> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x187538000 - 0x188501fff WebCore arm64  <f784cea3224136b1a484a0ab2cfe6c49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x188504000 - 0x18852dfff libxslt.1.dylib arm64  <ee7d42f377153be08acb66ef0e23ce6b> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x188530000 - 0x18860bfff WebKitLegacy arm64  <c5e86dcbe42a346fbc8e4348f20b0b0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x18860c000 - 0x1886c4fff CoreUI arm64  <bacbb777bd8d370eaced7715482597cb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x1886c8000 - 0x1886edfff DictionaryServices arm64  <57ed0f1ec6ba3b9d863ce1779c28224b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x1886f0000 - 0x1886f0fff HangTracer arm64  <e5d52de1bdc9359fa5bd342296ed4ec5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HangTracer.framework/HangTracer
0x1886f4000 - 0x188742fff PhysicsKit arm64  <dcf7b4ad47f931819a7932e67e3fe634> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x188744000 - 0x18881afff UIFoundation arm64  <f60afc23776d3b78b235b21d13367c53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x18881c000 - 0x189446fff UIKit arm64  <74822453a3473710a19d8e14887476ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x189448000 - 0x189469fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <76f7013f4dfb339f818ece965d5626ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x18946c000 - 0x189491fff DataAccessExpress arm64  <1d44ae1367253d7591c9cf2f5d1eb222> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x189494000 - 0x1894adfff NetworkStatistics arm64  <cd7ca8ce1976376db2da4d41867548b7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x1894b0000 - 0x18952bfff AddressBook arm64  <71260a3c82443a4bb92e4498d32214e1>
```

(Cut short due to max characters on questions).

Thanks!